# where we upload IRremote.h file

Tags: arduino

I have upload IRremote.h file into arduino->libraries->IRremote.h

but it gives error like

sketch_jan29a:4: error: 'IRsend' does not name a type
sketch_jan29a.ino: In function 'void setup()':
sketch_jan29a:14: error: 'irsend' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Could you post your code aswell? It would be most usefull.

Comment: does an example work?

Comment: also restart the IDE after coping the library into the above mentioned folder, so that IDE knows about it.

Answer (score 0):

you have added the library to de ide, now you have to add it to your sketch.

just add

```
#include "IRremote.h"
```

or sketch -> import library -> irRemote